# Neuroscientist new to coding here, trying to analyse a large CSV table with non-standard formatting in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, new-operator

So I've got almost non-existent coding background but I decided to try and learn some Python to optimise data analysis for my neuroscience research since it will save me hundreds of hours down the line.

I've decided to learn how to use pandas because from what I've gathered it would be the most intuitive way to work with the types of data my project involves. 
Basically I am doing animal behavioral studies using operant boxes which are running on a very weird and non-intuitive software made by some guy that used to work at our university. This software outputs a CSV file with a general structure being something like:

- the file starts with STARTDATA in the first cell
- first 10 lines are basically useless labels and titles in column 1
- then there is a header for the first subject
- then a set of 4 tables, separated by blank rows and words
- then a footer which is always the same for any subject
- this structure is repeated for every subject (12 in total)
- file ends with ENDDATA after the last footer

Image of the data structure:
https://imgshare.io/images/2020/03/26/Annotation-2020-03-26-182445.jpg

Example data:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f7119d8a4ce6a018dc1c138cdcd0662920200326194129/bc1104

At first I had a problem of telling pandas how to read this weird format. After a day of fiddling, I've managed to resolve this by skipping the first useless rows.

My question now is what would be the most effective way to extract all the columns with useful data for every subject and perform some calculations with it? The columns would always be the same for each subject but rows vary depending on the number of trials the subject has carried out.

I apologise for the vagueness of my request in advance but any help will really be appreciated... It's a little overwhelming when trying to figure everything out with no guidance...

Comment: The screenshot is really hard to read, would it be a problem to even just include a sample-even scrambled data- of the main structure of your file? i believe that would help others give more accurate solutions with tested code, other than that we could only give you inaccurate pseudo codes

Comment: This file isn't really amenable to standard parsing. You will have to split it with command line tools or write a custom parser. You should not trust the software that produced it to be well-written or correct in any way.

Comment: If you can, it might be worth fixing/modifying the software at some point.

Comment: @KareemEmad I have included dummy data now, hopefully it'll make sense to someone

Comment: @laquica Please include data in text form.

Comment: @a_guest I mean it's a CSV, you can open it in any notepad